# Is there an updated version of the ROS command cheat sheet?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across this while reading the ROS wiki: http://download.ros.org/downloads/ROScheatsheet.pdf

I know at least the rxgraph has been replaced by rqt_graph but does anyone know if there's a more updated sheet like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115151/is-there-an-updated-version-of-the-ros-command-cheat-sheet?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-01-06**:
Feel free to do it and share it to the community :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Meanwhile there is:

[announcement on ros-users](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Updated-ROS-cheat-sheet-td4020575.html)

[ros news citing the announcement](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/01/updated-ros-cheat-sheet-for-hydro-catkin.html)

direct link: http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/ros-cheat-sheet

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-11**:
There's now a copy of the cheatsheet on github at: https://github.com/ros/cheatsheet